# Magento data migration using two different servers

Tags: migration, magento2-migration-tool

My current Magento 1 site hosting on server which is not supported for Magento 2

So for the data migration and delta migration

I need to install my magento 2 on another server then need to remotely connect with Magento 1 database and then perform migration

My question is how to connect remote database with data migration tool ?

Is there any possibility to migrate data when magento 1 and Magento 2 hosted on 2 different servers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course you can do this

You have to use your "external IP" instead of using "localhost", you also need to use "3306" port (if you want to use this method you have to be sure that you are allowed to connect using external IP, please ask your hosting to allow it).

I have this point before and But I  had some difficulties to make connection between two server and to avoid this way, I only copied the database from old server to the new server (no need to copy Magento files only the DB), After this you can do the migration within the two DBs in the same server

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is definitely possible to migrate data when Magento 1 and Magento 2 hosted on 2 different servers.

Please edit your `config.xml` file from a data-migration-tool module in the vendor.

```
<source>
    <database host="<Mage1_hostname>" name="<Mage1_database>" user="<Mage1_User>" password="<Mage1_password>"/>
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="localhost" name="<Mage2_database>" user="<Mage2_User>" password="<Mage2_password>"/>
</destination>
```

Replace 1.9.2.4 with your Magento1 version.

After completed it, Please executes your appropriate `config.xml` file,

> php bin/magento migrate:settings vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.4/config.xml
>
> php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.4/config.xml

I hope this will help you.